# Detect pen drive

Tags: c, linux, usb-drive

I need to detect when a pen drive (or more) is connected. I would prefer low-level ways, but also high-level ways are good.
Development environment: C language on linux OS.

Comment: How do you define what is a pen drive and what is not?  Is a 64 GB 2.5" SSD in a USB enclosure a pen drive?  Is a 64 GB USB "stick" a pen drive?  An 8 MB USB stick?  An 8 MB SD card?  An 8 GB Android phone?  Do you have some scheme in mind to delineate which devices you are interested in and which you aren't?

Comment: I also need help on your questions. I'm only interested to USB pen drive ("stick" pen drive, nothing else with a "stick" USB adapter, etc) and I hope there is a way...

Answer (score 1):

udev - https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.kroah.com/linux/talks/ols_2003_udev_paper/Reprint-Kroah-Hartman-OLS2003.pdf

A quick tutorial on udev rules - http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html